# Library/package development - message when loading

Tags: r, package

is there any way to display a message when a user loads `library(myCustomLibrary)`?
Upon loading, I want to display a message that tells the user how to run all the test functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes.  You can use the `.onLoad`, `.onAttach`, or `.First.lib` functions to do whatever you want when the package is loaded.  I suggest looking at the help for those functions.  You would use `.onLoad` with a namespace, and `.First.lib` without.

One convention is that people will frequently put these commands in a separate `zzz.R` file, which is just used for package related code.

Answer (score 33):

Quick points (and updated edit in 2021):

- while if your package has a NAMESPACE, then `.onLoad()` is where you used to do this: but `.onLoad()` has been required to be 'silent'
- if your package has a NAMESPACE, then `.onAttach()` is where can call, preferably via `packageStartupMessage()` (which can be suppressed where `cat()` or `message()` cannot
- if your package does not have NAMESPACE, then you must add one now (and `.First.lib()` was where you used to do this) -- NAMESPACES have been mandatory for a few years now
- either way, use `packageStartupMessage()` instead of `cat()` so that users have a choice of suppressing this.

Comment: +1 indeed. Where do I have to put this? Which file of my package?

Comment: It used to matter, and people used `R/zzz.R` -- which now is mostly a convention. I think you can do `R/onLoad.R` just as well.

Comment: in the Hadley's book it is mentioned user *should* use `.onAttach()` instead `.onLoad()` for that purpose. He didn't explain why.
http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/r.html#r-code

Comment: I’m disappointed that even R CMD check now gives a note if it’s in `.onLoad()` instead of `.onAttach()`. My reason is this: if you call a function using `package::function()`, the startup message will not be shown if it’s in `.onAttach()`. In some cases, sources or references then remain unknown.

Comment: I mostly dislike the non-intuitive language around the two functions, but in 20+ years of package writing I have generally found that _Writing R Extensions_ is both authorative, and aligned with that `R CMD check` tests for.  Standards change, but as `NAMESPACES` are now common and required these distinctions make some sense.

Answer (score 2):

**Updated answer (2019):**

In the help section "Good practice" in `?.onAttach` the recommendation is now:

> Loading a namespace [= in `.onLoad`] should where possible be silent,
>   with startup messages given by .onAttach.
>   These messages (and any essential ones from .onLoad) should use 
>   `packageStartupMessage` so they can be silenced where they would be a distraction.

`R CMD CHECK` will complain if `.onLoad` is not silent...