# How to avoid printing a package's author message?

Tags: r, package, data.table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Library/package development - message when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192360/library-package-development-message-when-loading)

I want to set up a web interface using Rapache; however, the underlying R code uses packages that display a quick message from the author. E.g., for `data.table`,

```
Quick start guide : vignette("datatable-intro") Homepage : http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/
```

Is there a way to avoid this? I tried `suppressMessages()`, and the `quietly` option to `library()`, but to no avail.

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2192360/602276

Comment: Really? It seems that this person wants to print a message. I want to *avoid* printing it.

Comment: Did you try `suppressPackageStartupMessages`?

Comment: I hadn't, because the help on suppressMessages() suggests that it should also suppress package startup messages; however I now tried it, and it didn't work. However, I am now of the opinion that this problem is specific to `data.table` (and maybe other packages, but not all); presumably the startup message is written using cat() or an equivalent function rather than something that suppressMessages() would be able to suppress. I added a `data.table` tag as a consequence.

Comment: If it's done using `cat`, can you surround it with sink commands to reroute the output to a file (if that works for you)?

Comment: Better, contact the author of the package and encourage them to use the `packageStartupMessage()` function to write messages that are printed during load/attach.

Comment: Good advice from Gavin. The email address to use is returned by the R command: maintainer("<package name>")

Comment: Yes indeed Matt :) we have been bugging a few packages authors to alter their startup code to make it 'suppressable' which is preferred for scripting etc

Comment: Which I saw, and did (a few days ago) :-)

Comment: I agree.. The question is asked from a very different angle, meaning that merging the answers would be very misleading. It is true that there is some overlap; the information there is relevant here, and vice versa; but is that a sufficient reason to close a thread?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For data.table, this was done in commit 233 (2011.06.11 01:04:27) :

"onAttach now uses packageStartupMessage so the banner can be suppressed by those annoyed by banners, whilst still being helpful to new users"

This is in v1.6.1 available from R-Forge, and may be released to CRAN soon.

I'll add a note to NEWS ...

Answer (score 2):

The brute force way of suppressing all output and messages for chatty packages is to use sink:

```
t <- tempfile()
tcon <- file(t,open="w+")
sink(file=tcon,type='output')
sink(file=tcon,type='message')
require(YOURLIBRARY)
sink(NULL,type='output')
sink(NULL,type='message')
unlink(t)
```

TAKE THAT YOU CHATTY PACKAGE!