# Should "onLoad.R" be included in the DESCRIPTION file "Collate" field?

Tags: r

I need to display a disclaimer message when my package is loaded.  After reading the posts

[Library/package development - message when loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192360/library-package-development-message-when-loading/2192671#2192671)
[Loading depending packages using .onLoad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5294679/loading-depending-packages-using-onload/5297460#5297460)

I now have a `zzz.R` file that contains only

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
    packageStartupMessage('Regarding data obtained from www.retrosheet.org:\n
    The information used here was obtained free of charge from  
    and is copyrighted by Retrosheet. Interested parties may
    contact Retrosheet at "www.retrosheet.org"', domain = NULL, appendLF = TRUE)
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Do I have to call `.onLoad` somewhere? Or does that happen automatically?
2. I'm using the `Collate` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file.  Does `zzz.R` need to be added to that list?

---

As a check, I run the following code.  The package startup message appears when using `install`, but not when calling `library`, which I expect.

```
> library(devtools)
> install()
...
Reloading installed saber
Regarding data obtained from www.retrosheet.org:

The information used here was obtained free of charge from  
and is copyrighted by Retrosheet. Interested parties may
contact Retrosheet at "www.retrosheet.org"
...

> detach(package:saber)
> library(saber)

Attaching package: ‘saber’

The following objects are masked _by_ ‘.GlobalEnv’:

    getTeamData, relatedBatting
```

Comment: Must include. Doesn't matter where. Called automatically.

Comment: Thanks much. Do you have a hint as to why the `.onLoad` message prints when calling `devtools::install` but not `library` ?

Comment: it should print on library(mypackage), but only when the package was not loaded already

Comment: You should switch to using roxygen2.  Note that in detach the unload parameter defaults to FALSE.  Try using unload=TRUE and then reloading.

Comment: Every time I try to build I get Exit Status 1 and `pdflatex not found!`  Do I have to install that as well?  I have `roxygen2` installed.

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah but you don't appear to use roxygen style comments in your code as far as I can tell from your github repo.

Comment: @Dason, right, I don't.  But don't go by that repo, I don't update it often.  many more files are strictly on my personal machine as I'm still learning how to push commits from RStudio.

Comment: @RichardScriven Sounds like you aren't using github properly ;)

Comment: As a word of warning - I've personally lost a month of work on a package because I used github like you currently are.  I would suggest pushing much more regularly.  What harm can it do?

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  I really didn't know people were looking at it.  It's a bit embarrassing in its current state.  I did just send some new functions to `myUtils` though.

Comment: .onAttach is the hook searched when called via library(pckg)... https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-hooks.html